# Auto update row that matches id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `posts (id, num_c)`  and `comments (post_id)`. After inserting a comment into the comments table, is there a way I can trigger an auto increment on the `num_c`  column   of the post with the matching `post_id` of the just inserted comment?

I can run two queries one after the other but I thought there should be a way the DB manages this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using SQL Triggers. A Trigger is a way through which the DB automates some of the work that would have do be done when some dataset changes. The general syntax for a trigger is (as shown in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm):

```
    CREATE [OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER trigger_name 
    {BEFORE | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } 
    {INSERT [OR] | UPDATE [OR] | DELETE} 
    [OF col_name] 
    ON table_name 
    [REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS n] 
    [FOR EACH ROW] 
    WHEN (condition)  
    DECLARE
       Declaration-statements
    BEGIN 
       Executable-statements
    EXCEPTION
       Exception-handling-statements
    END;
```

Comment: how can i apply this to my problem? getting the post_id from the inserted comment seems like a challenge

Comment: The comments table that you mentioned has only one column called post_id. Are you asking how to parse and extract a value from the posted comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create trigger in this way

CREATE TRIGGER t_inserted AFTER INSERT ON comments 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CALL update_posts();
END;
```

Comment: Hi, that's basically a good suggestion and the right start, but could you be more specific here and provide a working example? Your example looks like an update is performed on all posts when a comment is added. But OP wants to know how to increment a value of a specific post when a new comment has been added to it.